# locking a python script on my PI

Tags: python

I have a script script_1.py that when runs from the command line, it works, but when called by the system it does not. I think it must be being called whilst it's already running. Could someone please  explain this line please:

> fcntl.flock(fh,fcntl.LOCK_EX|fcntl.LOCK_NB)

```
  import os
    import sys
    import fcntl
    fh=0
    def run_once():
        global fh
        fh=open(os.path.realpath(__file__),'r')
        try:
            fcntl.flock(fh,fcntl.LOCK_EX|fcntl.LOCK_NB)
        except:
            os._exit(0)

    run_once()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation on your line:
LOCK_EX – acquire an exclusive lock
LOCK_NB - check if acquiring a lock is not blocked

The problem could well be in '__file__'
This special variable is set to the name provided by the module loader. If the loader does not make filename information available, this variable is set to None.

This bit is how I lock my scripts, its not using a function as yours does:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#START OF FILE
import fcntl, sys
pid_file = '/run/lock/LOCKFILE-FOR-THIS-SCRIPT.pid'
fh = open(pid_file, 'w')
try:
    fcntl.lockf(fh, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
except IOError:
    # another instance is running
    print 'Error: Another instance is running...'
    sys.exit(0)

# FOLLOWING IS THE NORMAL CODE
```